# Trying to use ref as an incrementing counter in a React component- gap in values occurs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**I've reproduced the issue I'm having in [this sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/useref-problem-z0f1r?file=/src/App.js)**

I'm trying to merge two arrays of objects stored in state in a React component.

The second one is created asynchronously (in my example this is done by clicking the button once).

On each array item I want to add an "offset" value to each one which increments on each item in the array. To keep track of where the offset is up to, I assumed I need to use a `ref`.

However when I do this, a mysterious gap appears in offset values when the second array is added. The gap is related to the number of items in the second array. It's almost like the "useEffect" that merges the new arrays is being run twice and the first time is ignored. I've been trying to debug this for hours now and I can't work out where the gap is coming from.

What should I be doing to acheive my desired result?

I'm guessing it's something I don't understand about useRef() or perhaps I should be using another React Hook somewhere? Please help!

The demo code is as follows:

```
import { useState, useRef, useEffect } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [array1, setArray1] = useState([{ id: 1 }, { id: 2 }, { id: 3 }]);
  const [array2, setArray2] = useState([]);
  const offset = useRef(0);

  const handleClick = () => {
    setArray2([{ id: 4 }, { id: 5 }, { id: 6 }]);
  };

  //handle Initial load
  useEffect(() => {
    setArray1((prevArray) => {
      const newArray = prevArray.map((item) => {
        offset.current = offset.current + 10;
        return { ...item, offset: offset.current };
      });

      return [...newArray];
    });
  }, [setArray1]);

  //merge the array 2 with array 1
  useEffect(() => {
    setArray1((prevArray) => {
      const newArray = array2.map((item) => {
        offset.current = offset.current + 10;
        return { ...item, offset: offset.current };
      });

      return [...prevArray, ...newArray];
    });
  }, [setArray1, array2]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Incrementing offset problem</h1>
      <p>Offsets are not what I expected when adding new items to array</p>
      <p>
        I expect the offsets to continue in increments of one but instead there
        is a gap of 3
      </p>
      <h4>Array 1</h4>
      <ul>
        {array1.map((item) => (
          <li key={item.id}>
            Item ID: {item.id}, Item offset: {item.offset}
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>

      <button onClick={() => handleClick()}>Add new 3 new items</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: `It's almost like the "useEffect" that merges the new arrays is being run twice` That's exactly what's happening, thanks to StrictMode.

Comment: @ChrisG Thanks so much for the reply. Can you tell me: Is there a better method I can use to acheive this functionality without producing this error? Or am I doing it correctly (I just have to ignore the error in development)? Any further pointers would be much appreciated.

Comment: You could read the offset of the last item instead, and use that when you append. Or just disable strict mode.

Comment: @ChrisG You are my hero. Thank you   . For anyone interested in the solution I've used - I forked my initial sandbox here: https://codesandbox.io/s/useref-problem-solved-66p5y?file=/src/App.js